# How to correctly add meta values as search keys using Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I currently have this a meta fields that are registered to the post, and another post type.

I was able to register the metafields correctly and I am able to do a POST for me articles through REST API.

What I am trying to figure out now is how can I add the meta key fields as search keys when I try to do a GET request through the rest API.

I searched through google but I am getting outdated resources.

I currently have this code:

```
$this->post_types = array ( 'post', 'events' );

foreach( $this->post_types as $field ) {

    add_filter("rest_" . $field . "_query", function ($args, $query) {

        $args["meta_query"]   = "event_id";
        $args["meta_query"]   = "event_date";     

        return $args;

    }, 10, 2);
}
```

But when I try to search using: `/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[meta_query][event_id]=15432` I am getting incorrect results.

Is there something in my code that I missed? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this? I have the same issue